# SQL average of selected values

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

How could i get the average value of the following values I found out using this query:

```
SELECT Title, GrossProfit FROM Cinema

ORDER BY GrossProfit DESC 

LIMIT 3
```

I tried using GROUP BY, but It gives me an error, I am quite new so would appreciate some help!

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Please show us some data.  Your question does not make complete sense.

Comment: `select  AVG(column1) from table Group by column1`

Comment: Do you want all three rows, with the Title and GrossProfit, ***plus*** an additional field showing the average of the three GrossProfits?  Or just a single number averaging those three rows?  etc, etc, etc.  *(In other words, please give examples...)*

Comment: I added the picture, I need the average value from 5 I selected as seen in the picture

Comment: Now it's `5` instead of `3`?  Also, please read my whole comment?  You haven't actually answered what you want in terms of output.

Comment: del del del del

Comment: I apologise, the limit can be adjustable, can't it? I want to select the bottom 5 values, select those 5 bottom values and return the average

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images. (Nor links to images...)

Answer (score 3):

Presumably, you want the average of `grossprofit`, not `title`.  If so, use a subquery:

```
SELECT AVG(GrossProfit)
from (SELECT Title, GrossProfit
      FROM Cinema
      ORDER BY GrossProfit DESC 
      LIMIT 3
     ) c;
```

Comment: Why bother even selecting the title, and I think its presence in the subquery could be confusing.

Comment: Would it be possible to select the Limit, for example 5, so that the bottom 5 is selected, by ASC and then get an average for those bottom 5 values, a single integer? There are 20 values in total GrossProfit in the table

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The question is:  "How could i get the average value of the following values I found out using this query".  I don't usually make this stuff up.

Comment: Plus one to you...not saying at all that your answer be wrong, just that we don't need to select unnecessary columns.

Answer (score 0):

> MySQL AVG() function retrieves the average value of a given
>   expression. If the function does not find a matching row, it returns
>   NULL.

So try this

```
SELECT AVG(GrossProfit) FROM Cinema
```

Comment: How would this account for the `LIMIT 3`?

Comment: Because in this case it's a non-obvious concern.  Adding `ORDER BY x LIMIT 3` won't give what the OP asked for, it would require a sub-query, as per @GordonLinoff's answer.